# correct formatting for JSON-LD markup

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'm trying to add some JSON-LD markup to my webpages. Here is what i've written

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "WebPage",
"url": "http://www.example.com",
"name": "Title goes here"
}
</script>
```

^^this validates ok. Pretty basic :-) However, I would like to add some additional descriptive properties to each page.

EDIT: Here is what I tried to put together, which didnt validate:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
   {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage,
   "name": "Title goes here"
    "description": "Description goes here"
 "significantLink":{
"URL": "http://example.com/page"
"URL": "http://example.com/page2"
"URL": "http://example.com/page3"}
  "relatedLink":
{
"URL": "http://example.com/anotherpage"
"URL": "http://example.com/anotherpage2"
"URL": "http://example.com/anotherpage3"
}
}
</script>
```

What would help me better understand the formatting would be an expanded example with correctly formatted extra JSON-LD properties included. Can someone please explain how to correct my example including the following properties?

'description'
'keywords'
'similarLink'
'relatedLink'

If there are other tags you think should be included for good markup, please mention too

Comment: Did you try to add these additional properties? If yes, please show us what you’ve tried. Stack Overflow isn’t really the right place to request examples.

Comment: There are examples in the schema.org documentation. http://schema.org/WebPage You can probably find other examples here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=schema.org+webpage+[json-ld]

Comment: thanks - I've edited my post to include what I tried to put together earlier based on the schema documentation. I couldnt find any working examples of the markup for significantLink + relatedLink.

Comment: I looked at some of the other examples here on stack that @inf3rno linked to and came up with this:  
`<script type="application/ld+json">  
{   
"@context": "http://schema.org",   

"@type": "WebPage", 
"name": "name of web page",   
"description": "same content as Description meta tag"   
"significantLink": "http://example.com/page"  
"relatedLink": "http://example.com/anotherpage"  


}  
</script>`  
However this doesnt validate and I can't find any working examples of JSON-LD using significantLink or relatedLink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you have in your last comment is not valid JSON, because you're missing the commas after some of the property values. I suggest using the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) to validate the JSON and the JSON-LD syntax.

Here's an example of a single item for each property:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{ 
  "@context": "http://schema.org", 
  "@type": "WebPage", 
  "name": "name of web page", 
  "description": "same content as Description meta tag",
  "keywords": "test, example",
  "significantLink": "http://example.com/page",
  "relatedLink": "http://example.com/anotherpage"
}
</script>
```

To add more than one `signigicantLink` or `relatedLink` simply make the properties arrays. You can also make the `keywords` property an array if you'd rather not concatenate them together into one string.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{ 
  "@context": "http://schema.org", 
  "@type": "WebPage", 
  "name": "name of web page", 
  "description": "same content as Description meta tag",
  "keywords": ["test", "example"],
  "significantLink": [
    "http://example.com/page",
    "http://example.com/page2"
  ],
  "relatedLink": [
    "http://example.com/anotherpage",
    "http://example.com/anotherpage2"
  ] 
}
</script>
```